# PHP Session variables to redirect pages

Tags: php

I have couple of html pages with user forms with applied PHP on them to read and write the data on text files. What I would like to do it based on the session variable on a current page to redirect to the next html page but don't know how to implement it.

HTML 1:

```
<div class="enterUserId">
      <h4>Please enter your user ID:</h4>
      <form method="post" action="processUserID.php">
        <input type="text" name="userID" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="intro">
      </form>
</div>
```

HTML 2:

```
<form method="post" action="processUserID.php">
  <select name="rank1" id="select1" size="1" style="width:80px;" required >
                    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled hidden>Rank</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                  </select>

<input type="submit" value="Proceed" name="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['userID'])){

      $myfile = fopen("temp/userID.txt", "w");
      $userID = $_POST['userID'].";\n";
      for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        fwrite($myfile, $userID);
      }
      //what potentionally needs to be handled by session variables
      header("Location: main.html");
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      $ranks = fopen("temp/ranks.txt", "w");
      $selected_val = $_POST['rank1'].";\n".$_POST['rank2'].";\n".$_POST['rank3'].";\n".$_POST['rank4'].";\n".$_POST['rank5'].";\n".$_POST['rank6'].";";
      fwrite($ranks, $selected_val);
      header("Location: main2.html");
      }
```

?>

So, I need to include something like this to replace the navigation but not sure how to implement it:

```
session_start();

   if (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
      $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
   }else {
      $_SESSION['counter']++;
   }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually session variable  is a condition which has to be checked for redirection. So location redirect is must. Also use cookie rather than session